# MySQL date and datetime formats unrecognized by Data

Tags: looker-studio

I've linked Google data studio with a MySQL database using the standard connector.  everything works fine except for the datetime fields.
I have these 2 fields in MYSQL
R_date 2020-07-16 09:31:25 which is DATETIME datatype
and
D_date 2020-09-13 10:32:24 which is TIMESTAMP datatype
both formatted in Data Studio as text.

Answer (score 0):

using TODATE function solve my issue and date appear properly in data studio

```
TODATE(R_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','%Y-%m-%d')
```